# Gallery Jquery Pager

Tags: views, javascript

I have created a "partners" block in the rightmenu of my theme .. it works perfect and all, but it shows only 6 partners (set from views settings) with newest first .. now my problem is i want to have a "view all" button, also i want to have a pager with jquery transition to view next 6 partners etc.

how can i do this? also, what modules do i need for this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I would advise splitting this into two questions.  First, set up the pager and the "view all" (which is probably just a link to another display of the view that has different properties set).  Once you figure out how to get that working, then ask another question about adding the jquery effects.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thank you for your reply. i do know how to set up the grid with pagination in views .. i just dont know what module or how i integrate jquery to make the slide to next objects of box.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this module [views_load_more](http://drupal.org/project/views_load_more)

Comment: Hi Smile. thank you for your reply, but that does not seem to do the trick .. i dont know if i was unclear in my description, but i want like a grid of 6 thumbs, with arrows left and right .. then on click it should not refresh page but just simply slide to the next 6 thumbnails .. -if possible, with autoplay.

Comment: Oh, may be i don't understand, sorry.
Look at this modules http://drupal.org/project/jcarousel or http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow - they can create slideshow with different navigation options

Comment: Hi again .. no problem , thank you for your time :D . about Jcarousel, its still yellow on downloadpage, and i think maybe that is why the nav buttons in it dont work .. i try and click next or prev but nothing happends in preview mode .. i already did have jcarousel .. about views slideshow, can you add jquery to it?